# Unity3D or UDK or OPENGL from scratch?

Tags: opengl, iphone, unity, udk

I am just very confused which I should choose in terms of high end game development. The application that I am designing is pretty simple, requires some 3D, and some effects. I am looking at a game similar to ping pong, but with high textures and graphics. I will just need web services to submit high scores.

From my description, you can see that its pretty straight forward and I am confused whether I should use **Unity3D** or **UDK** or write the entire application myself with **openGL** (which will take a lot of time though).

If you had faced this dilemma before, and chose for a particular graphics engine, please provide your suggestions and reasons as to why that was better. It would be helpful.

Also, how can this affect in terms of *investment* and *revenue* ?

Comment: "Which technlogy should I use?" questions have become off topic since the creation of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This topic appears very regularly here.  I'd suggest reading through the [many other iterations](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=udk%20unity) to get further answers.

In my opinion, UDK is good for making first person shooters and little else.  The online documentation isn't much beyond automatically created documentation from the source files (what comes out of things like Doxygen).  I'm working on a student project in UDK that is a third person platformer.  It's been unnecessarily difficult at times.

Unity is pretty fast to learn, well-documented, and capable of a variety of game types.  Its versatility can make some tasks trickier than others, however, but the Unity community can be pretty helpful in finding answers to your questions.  I think it's a good choice for simple or quick projects.

Writing it on your own in OpenGL could be a great learning or practicing experience if that's what you want.  Not knowing your skillset, though, makes it hard to know whether it's worth it.  If you want something done quickly, doing it on your own may not be the best decision.  If you want to learn a lot about the process (engine, game, 3D programming, etc.), it may be a good idea.

Comment: Can you provide you comments interns of investment and revenue ?

Comment: And yeah, I think I fit somewhere in your last paragraph. I am in a  state where I need to get this done quick, and at the same time, learning and practicing would be extremely beneficial and I am weighing my options...

Comment: You need to be more specific what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In case of such a simple game design idea, I'd use Unity3D if I were you.

Alternatively, it might be worth checking out Panda3D or a game development focused programming language such as Blitz3D or Dark Basic Pro. 
All of them are pretty good in terms of flexibility, performance and development speed.

Answer (score 0):

For every project the same rule applies: "Good, Cheap, Fast. Pick any two."

I found a good management tool. Draw a circle. Write the three options evenly spaced on the edge. Determine where on the edge of the circle you want your project to fall. Draw a line from the center to your spot. (Those plastic signs with clock hands attached that are captioned "We're closed! Be back at", work fine). Pin it up on the wall and look at it when you're making decisions.

You can be good and cheap but expect to spend years doing everything yourself from scratch. 
You can be fast and cheap but don't expect to win any awards.
etc.